# file not found in "loadpicture" instruction of image control

Tags: excel, vba

I am coding a button to add  pictures in vba image control of Excel sheet.
but message "file not found  appears"

first I tried this:

```
Set mydocument = Worksheets(1)
mydocument.Shapes.AddPicture _
    "D:\Afshar\programming\PIAGGIO\liberty 150", _
    True, True, 100, 100, 70, 70
```

error was: "application-defined or object-defined error"

then I tried:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim path As String

path = "D:\Afshar\programming\PIAGGIO\liberty 150"

Set WS = Sheets(1)

With WS
.OLEObjects("Image1").Object.Picture = 
LoadPicture("D:\Afshar\programming\PIAGGIO\LIBERTY S 50")

End With
```

error was: file not found"

Comment: Does the image file have a file extension (.png, .jpg, .bmp)?

Comment: I also checked it with extension .jpg, but no result I got.

Comment: When you use Windows Explorer do you see any extensions on your picture files?  In the Explorer folder options dialog make sure you have unchecked "Hide extensions for known file types"